# Customize the MVC5 ASP.net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Can the new MVC5 ASP.net Identity setup be customized like the old one in MVC4 (ie Providers)

As some projects dont need the Claims or Logins tables in the DB as the simply do not use them.

I usually create a custom DB schema to how users and roles. Is there a way to customize the new Identity system to handle this or am i stuck trying to use the current schema?

Comment: Really no one has tried to customize the new ASP.net Identity? I just basically want users and roles

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do.

1. Use custom profile information. Look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx
2. Use claims. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx.  It's briefly explained in the first two comment sections.  The 2nd comment has a link and though for WCF, the concept is similar.

Comment: They seem fine to me. Just checked again.